# Udev: no takes rule for gps

Tags: 10.04, usb, udev, gps

I'm trying to create a udev rule for a GPS.
I tried several ways but can not get the device to be captured by the rule:

lsusb:

Bus 002 Device 007: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port

```
    udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyUSB0)

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0':
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/ttyUSB0':
    KERNELS=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"
    DRIVERS=="pl2303"
    ATTRS{port_number}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0':
    KERNELS=="2-1:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="pl2303"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="03"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{modalias}=="usb:v067Bp2303d0300dc00dsc00dp00icFFisc00ip00"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb2/2-1':
    KERNELS=="2-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="20"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="067b"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="2303"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0300"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="7"
    ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Prolific Technology Inc."
    ATTRS{product}=="USB-Serial Controller"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb2':
    KERNELS=="usb2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="  0mA"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="157"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0001"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0206"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="2"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 2.6.32-34-generic-pae uhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{product}=="UHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:10.0"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:10.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="uhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x1106"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x3038"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1106"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x3038"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0300"
    ATTRS{irq}=="21"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="ff"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
    ATTRS{modalias}=="pci:v00001106d00003038sv00001106sd00003038bc0Csc03i00"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS=="
```

i tried with these rules, i tried With These rules, but none works:

```
#DRIVERS=="sierra",SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="03",SYMLINK="ttyACM10"
#DRIVERS=="pl2303",SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial",ATTRS{idVendor}=="067b",ATTRS{idProduct}=="2303",ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00",SYMLINK="ttyGPS"
#DRIVERS=="pl2303",SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial",ATTRS{idVendor}=="067b",ATTRS{idProduct}=="2303",ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Prolific Technology Inc.",ATTRS{port_number}=="0",SYMLINK="ttyGPS"
#DRIVERS=="pl2303",SUBSYSTEM == "usb-serial", ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:10.0", SYMLINK="ttyAGSP"
#DRIVERS=="pl2303",SUBSYSTEM=="tty"ATTRS{idVendor}=="067b",ATTRS{idProduct}=="2303",ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:10.0",SYMLINK="ttyGPS"
```

the system ever generate the following symlink:

```
[ 4516.789581] pl2303 2-1:1.0: pl2303 converter detected
[ 4516.803239] usb 2-1: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

Any fix to it?
Thanks!!